# Add extra column to table in add to cart page

Tags: magento-1.9

Need to add extra column to add to cart functionality, How I can do that. Any reference link or anything would be appreciated.

I followed from `cartController` to `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote` to check how values are inserting. But I know using `setExampleCoumnName()` or`setData()` I can pass value to custom column. From here How I can go further?

I am trying to call the event to insert value to sales_flat_order_item table,

```
public function convertymyquotevalueintoordertable($observer)
    {
        $quoteItem = $observer->getEvent()->getItem();
        $orderItem = $observer->getOrderItem();
        if ($quoteItem->getPrintPrice()) {
            $orderItem->setPrintPrice($quoteItem->getPrintPrice());
        }
        return $this;
    }
```

In config.xml file of sales module,

```
    <sales_convert_quote_item_to_order_item>
        <observers>
            <mage_sales>
                <type>model</type>
                <class>mage_sales/observer</class>
                <method>convertymyquotevalueintoordertable</method>
            </mage_sales>
        </observers>
    </sales_convert_quote_item_to_order_item>
</events>
```

Let me the mistakes I did here.

Comment: you want to add column in cart page?

Comment: I mean, To the database I have to add one column in cart page. I checked the code, But confused.

Comment: Please clarify the  question .

Comment: which link,you have tried

Comment: I am following this link, https://jutesenthil.wordpress.com/2014/08/20/set-custom-price-in-magento-and-save-custom-values-into-sales_flat_quote_item-and-sales_flat_order_item-magento/

Comment: I guess if you are adding something to quote_item and order_item, those must be a part of invoice_item, shipment_item and creditmemo_item tables as well. For a better approach, you must follow this link which covers every bit. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27937681/update-how-i-can-create-new-column-in-table-sales-flat-quote-item-and-add-da

Comment: @shivani, I understood clearly now what they have explained in that link, Just a small doubt is If I create a custom module in local folder. At the time of checkout how I can call them to the core checkout functions?

Comment: Normally, you need to write <frontend> routers to call your checkout `after` or `before` = `Mage_Checkout`. Let me know if this is clear.

Comment: Not that cleared, Could you please reply with proper answer?

Answer (score 2):

Adding a custom comment box for each item in the cart So you can understand how you can add extra column in cart page and insert your value in database table First lets add the text area field for each item.

In your theme, for the file: template/checkout/cart.phtml
Add the new heading along with other heading for cart items.

> `<th><?php echo $this->__('Comments') ?></th>`

In the file: template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml
Add a new column

```
<td class="a-center">
<textarea name="cart[<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>][comments]" rows="3" cols="20"><?php echo $_item->getItemcomment() ?></textarea>
</td>
```

For Older version of Magento it would be:

```
<td class="a-center">
<textarea name="cart[<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>][comments]" rows="3" cols="20"><?php echo $this->getItemItemcomment($_item) ?></textarea>
</td>

Doing up to this. should show the text area added
```

[image: add comment box in cart page]

The next step is to save the comment in DB, when customer update the cart.

So add a new field ‘itemcomment’ in the table ‘sales_flat_quote_item’. (For older version of Magento the table would be ‘sales_quote_item’)

Now we are going to add the code which will do the DB operation. For this we will need to modify the file:
app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Cart.php (Note: If you are planning to upgrade your Magento setup, copy this file to local & modify.)

Here we need to add some code to the function updateItems(), such a way that the function should now look like below:

```
public function updateItems($data)
 {
     Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_cart_update_items_before', array('cart'=>$this, 'info'=>$data));

     foreach ($data as $itemId => $itemInfo) {

         $item = $this->getQuote()->getItemById($itemId);
         if (!$item) {
             continue;
         }

         if (!empty($itemInfo['remove']) || (isset($itemInfo['qty']) && $itemInfo['qty']=='0')) {
             $this->removeItem($itemId);
             continue;
         }

         $qty = isset($itemInfo['qty']) ? (float) $itemInfo['qty'] : false;
         if ($qty > 0) {
             $item->setQty($qty);
         }

     /* Start: Custom code added for comments */
     if(!empty($itemInfo['comments'])) {

        $write = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');

        # make the frame_queue active
        $query = "UPDATE `sales_flat_quote_item` SET itemcomment = '".$itemInfo['comments']."' where item_id = $itemId";
$write->query($query);

        $item->setItemcomment($itemInfo['comments']);
     }
     /* End: Custom code added for comments */

     }

     Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_cart_update_items_after', array('cart'=>$this, 'info'=>$data));
     return $this;
 }
```

Showing the comment in Admin -> View Order

Add a new function getItemcomment() to the file below:
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/View/Items.php

If you are on version 1.5 or later.. add it to the file below.
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/View/Items.php

```
.
.
<tr class="headings">
    <th><?php echo $this->helper('sales')->__('Product') ?></th>
    <th><?php echo $this->helper('sales')->__('Comments') ?></th>
    <th><?php echo $this->helper('sales')->__('Item Status') ?></th>
.
.
.
```

Adding Column with comments. app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/items/renderer/default.phtml
Add a column for item comments juts before status columns to make it look a like below.

```
.
.
<td><?php echo $this->getItemcomment($_item) ?></td> <!-- New column added for item comments -->
<td class="a-center"><?php echo $_item->getStatus() ?></td>
.
.
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your example, I am using magento 1.9, Now I have followed the code. My question is do I need to add same column to sales_flat_order_item table?

Comment: @PreethamRao yes,   make a extra field named 'itemcomment'  in sales_flat_order_item table .. is this solve your problem or not?

Comment: I have created the extra column in sales_flat _order_item table, Shall i update same as you did in updateItems($data) function? I guess if your ans is yes, my problem is solved.

Comment: @PreethamRao Yes.. if  this one  solved your problem then marked as accepted answer and close it..  if not then explain your  problems

Comment: Any idea how to add custom price value to basetotall and grandtotal. So I should be able to access that till payment gateway? Example: 20.00(custom price)+(original product price). I want to add the price at the time of add to cart ajax call.

Comment: yes you can do it in admin panel while creating order.. 

if you want to show custom price options means allow user to put their price(bargaining) or automatic add your custom value to base price ??  am i getting right ?

Comment: @lalitmohan,can you please give me example for Magento 2.I am looking solution for Magento2.